# difference between suffixes '-ish' and '-y'

Tags: adjectives, suffixes, neologisms, nuance

Recently Prince Charles used the word 'Hitlery,' in the sense of "possessing some properties of Hitler."

Is there any difference between the suffixes *-ish* and *-y* ?

Comment: What makes you think there is some difference? What did your previous research reveal?  Please show what you have discovered in standard reference works, so we understand where you are coming from.

Comment: Perhaps other examples would make your question clearer: e.g is there a difference in meaning between: "bluey" and "bluish"; "hotty" and "hottish"; or "meany" and "meanish"? Could you find a link relating to the incident, and one where *Hitlerish* is used? I quite like this question, but it needs working on.

Comment: The adjectival suffix *-y* tends to denote a close resemblance to the respective noun, whereas *-ish* denotes only a vague resemblance.

Comment: Mari-Lou A: To my feeling, the difference between "meany" and "meanish" is quite vague and mostly stylistic.

The "Hitlery" case I mentioned is from http://www.newyorker.com/online/blogs/borowitzreport/2014/05/an-apology-from-prince-charles.html

I would rather say "Hitlerish" in this context, so the question is about the nuances of usage I cannot grasp.

Comment: Yes, the suffixes *-y* and *-ish* **are** different. Please look up the suffixes in a good dictionary.

Comment: @Anonym Source?

Comment: I didn't mean to insinuate changing your example, but rather use an example to explain the difference in nuance (perhaps) and ask if the same interpretation could be applied to HRH's usage.

Comment: @Anonym So 'Hitlerish' might mean 'having a moustache'? There are dubious continua involved here, and the terms aren't well-defined. grep sounds about right, though your response also contains truth.

Comment: One big difference is that -ish can be stressed to emphasize the fact that there are definite differences. So if asked "is Putin Hitlery?" one could response "well, he's Hitlerish" (with stress on the last syllable) to mean "yes but he's not exactly the same".

Comment: Prince Charles did NOT use the word Hitlery. Your New Yorker link is to a supposedly satrirical blog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Michael Quinion, *Ologies and Isms: A Dictionary of Word Beginnings and Endings* (Oxford, 2002) offers extensive entries for *-ish* and *-y*. The entry for *-ish* as a suffix forming adjectives is further subdivided into adjectives formed from nouns and adjectives formed from other adjectives:

> One set from nouns is of adjectives for a member of a nation. A second set from nouns is of adjectives that indicate its qualities or characteristics.... May are formed from proper names, often for a single use (***Ayckbournish***, ***Hockneyish***, ***Thurberish***). Though these examples are neutral in tone, the great majority are derogatory.... Examples formed from other adjectives suggest some quality that is roughly or somewhat like that of the adjective (***coldish***, ***dullish***, ***loudish***, ***moreish***, ***oldish***, ***sweetish***, ***tallish***, ***weakish***).

The entry for *-y* is even more extensive, stretching across three separate entries. The first of these is potentially relevant to the OP's question. Here are excerpts from it:

> **-y**  Also **-ey** *Full of; having the quality of; inclined to; apt to.* [Old English *-ig*, of Germanic origin.]
>
> Adjectives in this ending divide broadly into three group. In one they straightforwardly denote the quality of the nouns from which they derive.... A second group are to some extent dismissive or disparaging, often with a figurative or indirect association, such as ***beery***, ***boozy***, ***dreamy***, ***mousy***, ***tinny***. A third set indicates a close attachment or mild addiction to something, as in ***booky***, ***doggy***, ***horsy***.
>
> ...
>
> The ending is active and is often used to create informal terms which may be mildly negative in tone, frequently in a an attempt to communicate some quality that might be hard otherwise to describe briefly: ***bacony***, ***dancey***, ***designery***, ***Internetty***, ***jargony***, ***plasticky***, ***tabloidy***.

To sum up, Quinion appears to be saying that *-ish* creates adjectives that suggest a rough equivalence to the originating noun, often with a derogatory edge, and that *-y* creates adjectives that express the quality of or an inclination toward the originating noun, but that may be neutral, disparaging, closely associative, or mildly negative.

I can't for the life of me tell whether *Hitlery* is more disparaging than *Hitlerish* or less disparaging, and I doubt that Prince Charles can either.